I can't transfer the exact contents of cell to another cell
can some please help me
i'm new to vba & excel and i want to use cell reference. I want to transfer the exact same value / formats / contents of a cell to another cell. I want to make it exactly the same just like using copy paste but i want to use the formula so it automatically transfer the contents to another cell exactly the same.
Example:
I tried to use formula (=H2) in i2 but it paste the contents like this.


If you use a formula, it will just paste the value, never ever the format. You need to know that value in Excel means the real value of the cell and format is just how you see that value

Please remove vba from tags if you're only looking for fomulas solution.

As stated in the first comment, it is a matter of format. Even if between the two lines in the source cell a Carriage Return character exists, that cell cannot let it doing its job, without changing its format. Please, right click on the formula cell, choose Format Cells... - Alignment and check Wrap text, to see what the first comment wants to say...

If you accept the use of VBA, you can try this function:
Function UseVal(src As Range, dest As Range) As String
    dest. Value(11) = src. Value(11)
End Function

The code must be entered in the standard module.
You can use it in a worksheet, but not in the cell where you want the result to be, but in another free cell. Specify the source address and the destination address as arguments. Separator according to local settings.
These addresses can span several cells, but they must be the same size and shape.
If you delete a cell with a formula, the result remains, but it no longer responds to changes in the source. You can remove it manually.
It works for me, but I can't guarantee that it will work anytime and anywhere.


Clever!  Have not seen that use of .Value(11) before.  How did you discover that?

From Polish ExcelForum.pl http://www.excelforum.pl/viewtopic.php?t=72373

Note that a function is only triggered when Excel thinks that a recalculation is needed. This is the case if you modify the content of a cell, but not when you only modify the formatting. Generally, I think it's not a good idea to let a UDF modify the format of a cell
